# Cannot sign ClickOnce manifests after upgrading build agent to VS 2017

Tags: tfs, clickonce, tfsbuild

We have a solution with a pair of ClickOnce applications that are signed and published as part of the build. We have an on-premise TFS 2017 server, but until recently our projects were all being built using VS 2015. Under this scenario, we were able to build, sign, and publish the ClickOnce application and manifests automatically, and everything is fine.

We recently deployed a new build agent with VS 2017 installed, and I cannot get that agent to build the project. The MSBuild step fails trying to sign the output with an error:

```
error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\x86\Release\app.publish\FooBar.exe
```

There is no additional information in the error message -- no explanation as to why the signing failed. The build agent is installed as a service, with it's log on credentials set to a real domain account, that's also a local admin on the build machine, and the certificate is installed into that user's certificate store.

As an aside, if I take the `msbuild` command line out of the build agent's log and run that command on the build machine while logged in under the agent account, the build stage finishes fine with correctly signed output; it only fails when running through the TFS agent service.

I'm at a loss where else to go to find why the signtool step is failing; has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Have you checked your certificate? It could be expired

Comment: the certificate is brand new.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect "fix," but a workaround is to stop the build agent Windows service and to run the build agent in interactive mode from PowerShell.

```
PS C:\agent_directory> .\run.cmd
Scanning for tool capabilities.
Connecting to the server.
2018-07-24 18:19:39Z: Listening for Jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the build agent did not detect the environment changes (Maybe MSBuild Capability here) or something wrong with the detected version of MSBuild or missed other related capabilities after you installed the VS 2017.

Just check the agent capabilities, make sure the capability **MSbuild 15.0**  is detected. Generally the value should like this :

```
MSBuild_15.0    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\

MSBuild_15.0_x64 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\
```

So, you can try below things to narrow down the issue:

1. If they are all there, just try to restart the agent service, then
   check it again.
2. If they are missed, you can try to manually add them (in Settings->
   Agent Queues -> Agent Pool -> Agent -> Capabilities -> Add
   Capability). After that then trigger the build again. You can add
   some other needed capabilities with the same way.
3. Deploy a new agent, then check that again.
4. Try to build with the **MSBuild** task and specify the MSBuild
   location directly in it. Then check that again.
5. Recreate certificate, check in the changes, then try it again. (Go to the **property** of the Project ->
   Select the **Signing** tab -> Click '**create test certificate**'
   button)

Comment: None of these seemed to help; the capabilities were all there, and deploying a new agent had no effect. However, if we stop the agent _service_ and run the agent as a _user_, the build works fine, so I'm assuming there is some permissions problem related to the certificate store?